# Sorry, the form response could not be submitted. formResponse.submit() not working when form is collecting email addresses

Tags: google-apps-script

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106678/submitting-a-form-via-google-apps-script-and-collecting-email) is outdated and does NOT have the answer.

On this google issue recorded [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74537186), Google developers solved the problem on August 2018 - more recent than any other thread.

However, even after the google issue was resolved for many, it still does not work, but only displays an error message.

```
function submitForm(){
  var form = FormApp.openById('MY_ID_HERE');
  var itemResponse;
  var response = form.createResponse();
  var answers = ['answer1','answer2'];
  var items = form.getItems();
  for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
    var item = items[j];
    var title = item.getTitle();
    Logger.log('Title: ' + title);
    switch(j){
      case 0:
          itemResponse = item.asTextItem().createResponse(answers[j]);
          break;
      case 1:
          itemResponse = item.asTextItem().createResponse(answers[j]);
          break;      
    }
    Logger.log("Response: " + itemResponse.getResponse());
    response.withItemResponse(itemResponse); 
  }
  response.submit();
}
```

The code here works with a form with 2 short text questions.

However, when enabling email collection, the script gives the error message:

> Sorry, the form response could not be submitted. Please wait a few
>   minutes and try again.

Is there anyway of submitting a form via script editor with email collection? Everyone on the google issue thread had the same problem and it was apparently resolved, so I am *sure* it is possible without disabling and re-enabling email collection. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [submitting a form via Google apps script and collecting email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106678/submitting-a-form-via-google-apps-script-and-collecting-email)

Comment: @MaxMakhrov I do not need to use this feature anymore, but I appreciate the follow up. Your answer to that thread does look promising however.